# How to find shortest path in networkx without searchning back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have typical graph, it's a tree and I can find shortest path between two nodes:

```
nx.shortest_path(G, source=root, target=target)
```

But I don't know if there's a simple function which would disallow to search backwards. So namely, as input is:

```
nx.shortest_path(G, 5, 10)
```

> [5, 6, 10]

it's looking forward (down the tree), but if

```
nx.shortest_path(G, 5, 3)
```

> [5, 3]

it returns up the tree but should give None.

My question is: is there any simple way to get out or I just need to implement a custom function to check for this issue?

Comment: Use a `DiGraph()`

Comment: There is no "up", just directed or undirected

Comment: I used. It seems to work: just got `NetworkXNoPath: No path between 5 and 3.` so the only thing is to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments there is no "up" or "down" in a graph. You can create a directed graph using the class `DiGraph()`, where you get the error "NetworkXNoPath: No path between 3 and 1.", when you try to find the path against edge directions. In this case you can use `try` to catch the exception:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import NetworkXNoPath

G = nx.DiGraph([(1, 2), (2, 3), (4,2)]) # create a directed graph

nx.shortest_path(G, source=1, target=3)
# [1, 2, 3]

try:
    path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=3, target=1)
except NetworkXNoPath:
    path = None
```

Alternatively you can check if two vertices have any path at all:

```
nx.has_path(G, source=3, target=1)
# False

if nx.has_path(G, source=3, target=1):
    path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=3, target=1)
else:
    path = None
```

[image: Directed Graph]